# android create ProgressDialog in constructor

Tags: java, android

I created Activity that includes ProgressDialog and its methods.

```
public class ProgressActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    public final ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public void dismissPD() {
        if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    public void setPDMessage(String msg) {
        progressDialog.setMessage(msg);
    }

    public void showPD(String msg) {
        ProgressDialog.show(this, "", msg);
    }

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    public ProgressActivity() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        dismissPD();
    }

}
```

Now I extend my new activity from it, but I get `NullpointerException` inside constructur on `progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this)`
As I see, I have a wrong context when constructor runs. Is there a right approach to realize it in my way?

Comment: progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(youractivity.this)

Comment: progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this); move this to activity oncreate method.

Comment: I'd like to make progressDialog private on parent Activity. Is that possible?

Comment: Why are you creating an activity for a progressDialog? You can simply do this with a class(without extending an activity) and call it's method from the new Activity.

Comment: I do it as a suggestion for refactoring. The main thought is to realize progressdialog's methods once in the main activity and extend others from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by overriding `oncreate` mothod of the main Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
}
```